# Añadir multiples Matriz en lista de Martiz

Tags: array, angular, typescript

La verdad no se exactamente como describir lo que estoy buscando, pero intnto explicar lo.
Tengo una class "pedidos"

```
 @Input() order: Order[] = [];
```

que va mostrar los productos incluidos en el pedido tal como demuestra la imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
cada pedido tiene lista de productos que es un ChildComponent al selecinar productos en cada pedido, inforamcion que este producto esta realizado se guarda en en una lista.

```
prolist: Order[] = [];
```

el codigo de la lista:

```
lista[ior].prodmenu[ipr].proddone = isCheck; 
    for (let index = 0; index < ilepr; index++) {
      const elt = lista[index];
      this.prolist.push(elt);
    }
```

esto ocurre offline, para guardar los cabios hay que pinchar el boton Save.
El problema que tengo que al guardar un pedido el otro se cancela y tendria que selecionar lo otra vez. Lo qu quiero es que al selecioanr los productos en cada pedido se crea otra instancia de prolist, para poder guardar solo una instancia y no afecta lo demas. Que ocurre alog cono en esta imagen de ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vale he solucionado este problema añadiendo cada pedido a localStorage con diferente id(key).